# Android ICS: how to move out of stopped state

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I just read this:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Does this mean that no app will be able to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast, since all apps are in the stopped state after reboot?

Is there anyway to get the app out of the stopped state without user's actively launching it?

Comment: All apps are not in the stopped state after reboot. An app is in this so-called "stopped state" after installation and after the user force-stops the app from Settings.

Comment: What apps are not in the stopped state after reboot? I think my app is as it does not receive BOOT_COMPLETED message on ICS.

Comment: That means it was in the so-called "stopped state" before the reboot. Reboots have nothing whatsoever to do with the so-called "stopped state".

Comment: This is true. I rebooted the phone while my app is running and the BOOT_COMPLETED message was received. Thank you.